# Union type is not being detected

Tags: typescript

I have the following types defined:

```
export type Property =
  | BooleanProperty
  | NumberProperty
  | IntegerProperty
  | StringProperty
  | ObjectProperty
  | ArrayProperty;

export interface OneOf {
  oneOf: PropertyOrKeyword[];
}
export interface AnyOf {
  anyOf: PropertyOrKeyword[];
}
type Keyword = OneOf | AnyOf;
export type PropertyOrKeyword = Property | Keyword;
```

In my code, I then have this:

```
const val = parent[objName]; // This is a PropertyOrKeyword type
if ("oneOf" in parent[objName]) {
  const index = val.oneOf.findIndex(
    (obj: Property) => obj.title === title
  );
  val.oneOf[index] = ref(title);
}
```

When I hover over `val.oneOf`, however, I see the following error:

```
Property 'oneOf' does not exist on type 'PropertyOrKeyword'.
  Property 'oneOf' does not exist on type 'BooleanProperty'.
```

It seems that maybe there are too many types being unioned, and TypeScript isn't able to detect that `oneOf` is a field on one of those types? Or am I doing something weird here? Seems to me that this should be working, and [the `in` phrase](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) should help TypeScript discover that `val` is of the `OneOf` type.

Am I missing something here? Does it have to do with the recursive nature of the types?

Comment: `if ("oneOf" in parent[objName])` -> `if ("oneOf" in val)` It's a well-known limitation of TS, it doesn't track that `val` is `parent[objName]` and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript cannot understand that `val` and `parent[objName]` are the same object, even if the assignment is at the line before the check. You should check directly the `val` property.

```js
const val = parent[objName]; // This is a PropertyOrKeyword type
if (typeof val === "object" && "oneOf" in val) {
  const index = val.oneOf.findIndex(
    (obj: Property) => (obj as ({title: string})).title === title
  );
  val.oneOf[index] = ref(title);
}
```

Here is a complete [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nANhAhgOwAoCc6S6KAXigCMFl0BuAKFEigDkBXAWxIi21w4OLVfZYadaAEk0wCAHMOXPLyj82HYeGgBlYFgCWaKXJ4giUKAGctuqavoB5EgCsIAY2AH8R4nccvr0AIJYWCggbgoBQSAAPExoANZocADuaAB8NNQQAB5gcPhQIlChHtQmAD6w5KiYOPIgJVDlzMqcNYb15eKSMi3c7u1Qmjp6Rf1ezq6tfWVQ4cFF6Vk5ebqSWABmKE7QNmgQNmtQAN71cLv7AFyFk6A2WADSECCJuQAmANoAujQAvhnZucAoCsOBstjM0CB9kd6uhIWtLkVbg8nq9Pj9aGooMjnlgXsYdnsDuU-BD9jRFgD8pjEfdHji8cQig0sXTXukAPTsqDiMBMYCmajUJyncxQMAoLAQCSXABKzlekXMQykABorr0brSUbiUsZjiYTGAagBGS7GgBMKvqhpq5suG0QpggVoNYpqAGZLvrXQbToTLm9DvltMBkJcAOTAEPIY3h75qw5R0MQCNJ5DmuMJtMpqCR6MQd1xj7WqC-b40YVoUVwBwMFAsaDEABERtw5qbFZFgOzxib2fbNDWMRc2lOUElawAFNnzkrLABKaGuzlQAAicDMcAbwAAFpYoIkQzvg8maK7JcAmFg0CfkOjqCuAKKZZx80doQWV0UANxQiGM4qShIbw1vYdYNl8UArgAKnuphAvBKDqrUSKsriVKQNQ2gHNOahwAcv7-oQxFQE2oHjE2UAAGRUaRfr7JRuhQIRi7el%20gK6C8WTGIRAB09FrLxayceIXGZJOJaTqBCLXCAi6ELqUkOFAKDwZOib5pcc56N887zrxPbEcQ2b1POZ7MX%20-FnGsbycVkHzGBO075mZ1DfEAA) solving your code.

As a side note, you should also check that the `obj` has the title property or casting it to somewhat like `{ title: string }` before comparing the value of the `title` property in your `findByIndex` callback